# Using chai-as-promised and chai-bignumber together fails

Tags: javascript, chai, chai-as-promised

The following call

```
filestore.getBlockNumber.q(fileHash).should.eventually.bignumber.equal(blockNumber)
```

Fails with

```
AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to be an instance of string, number or BigNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue, and also fix it by changing the order in which the plugins are used:

```
chai.use(require('chai-bignumber'));
chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
```

Comment: This is also described in [this issue](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/244) and those referenced from there, in short: `use` chai-as-promised last and only *once*. If in doubt, refactor that stuff into an external file [just like `chai-as-promised` does](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/blob/master/test/support/setup.js) and [recommends](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#installation-and-setup).